# How to Store and display the output of shell command run in loop using with_lines

Tags: ansible

Below is the playbook i have created. I am not getting the way to store and display the output od the shell command and pass the same output to other play having different hosts.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: "check the connectivity with username for all the LLC servers from hosts.new file"
     shell: ssh dp794d@{{ item }} "date"
     register: result
     with_lines: cat "/home/capio/ansible/pmossWipm/day2/logs/ipAddress.txt"
   - debug: var=result
```

Now how can i display the result of register variable "result". I tried using the debug, but it didn't worked.

Below is the output of var=result

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"result": {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ssh dp794d@130.6.50.131 \"date\"",
            "delta": "0:00:00.237866",
            "end": "2017-05-09 08:59:13.918581",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "ssh dp794d@130.6.50.131 \"date\"",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "warn": true
                },
                "module_name": "command"
            },
            "item": "130.6.50.131",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2017-05-09 08:59:13.680715",
            "stderr": "   _________________________________________________________________\n\n    This system is restricted to ABC authorized users for business\n    purposes.  Unauthorized access is a violation of the law. This\n    service may be monitored for administrative and security reasons.\n    By proceeding, you consent to this monitoring.\n   _________________________________________________________________\n\n ,
            "stdout": "Tue May  9 08:59:13 EDT 2017",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "Tue May  9 08:59:13 EDT 2017"
            ],
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ssh dp794d@130.6.50.132 \"date\"",
            "delta": "0:00:00.245660",
            "end": "2017-05-09 08:59:14.430728",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "ssh dp794d@130.6.50.132 \"date\"",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "warn": true
                },
                "module_name": "command"
            },
            "item": "130.6.50.132",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2017-05-09 08:59:14.185068",
            "stderr": "   _________________________________________________________________\n\n    This system is restricted to ABC authorized users for business\n    purposes.  Unauthorized access is a violation of the law. This\n    service may be monitored for administrative and security reasons.\n    By proceeding, you consent to this monitoring.\n   _________________________________________________________________\n\n   [,
            "stdout": "Tue May  9 08:59:14 EDT 2017",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "Tue May  9 08:59:14 EDT 2017"
            ],
            "warnings": []
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please attach the output of `- debug: var=result`.

Comment: I have updated the output of var=result in the above question. Please let me know if you need any further inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can store result to file as follows:

```
- copy:
    content: '{{ result.results | map(attribute="stdout") | list | join("\n") }}'
    dest: /tmp/out.txt
```

Comment: Current Ansible ver - 2.2.0.0 and below is the error-

TASK [copy] ********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'. String: {{ result.results | map(attribute=\"stdout\") | list | join(\"\\\\n\") }}"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/capio/ansible/pmossWipm/day2/playbooks/day2_activity.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1

Comment: Please upgrade your ansible and required modules to more recent version.

Comment: Current version is 2.2 and seems it is latest one as per the link - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html which i referred. Can you please suggest which exact version is required for this

Comment: sorry for late response, please update Jinja2 to 2.8 as well